# Add value to a list, extracting the value from a loop and automatically assigning it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

After the final result of an algorithm which is the list `x`, i would like to print a variable `z` where i add to the list `x` the corresponding values of `y_and_value`

For example `y_and_value` is this:

```
('Hokkaido-Nikko', [1.36])
('Timra-Orebro', [1.44])
('Vaxjo-Lulea', [1.12])
('Yokohama-Tohoku', [1.23])
```

I would like to print the variable `z` like this and get these output, because these two hockey matchs are the only two in `x`:

```
('Hokkaido Nikko', [1.36])
('Yokohama-Tohoku', [1.23])
```

How can I get 1.36 and 1.23 assigned to these two matches?
(obviously I don't want to manually specify 1.36 and 1.23, because this is just an example and the numbers in the loop can be many, so they have to assign themselves automatically)

My code:

```
#Final result of an algorithm
x = {('Hokkaido-Nikko', 'JAP'),
     ('Yokohama City-Tohoku', 'JAP')
    }

y = {('Vaxjo-Lulea'),
     ('Hokkaido-Nikko'),
     ('Timra-Orebro'),
     ('Yokohama-Tohoku')}

prox_list = [row for row in y]
print(" ")

for row in prox_list:
    numbers = {(1.23),(1.44),(1.36),(1.12)}

#Assign numbers to y 
result={}
for key, value in zip(prox_list, numbers):
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)       
for key, value in result.items():
    y_and_value = key, value
    print(y_and_value)
```

Comment: You're using sets, which are unordered.

Comment: @mozway i'm new to python. so how could i fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if I misunderstood your questions.

Assuming that `x` is an output from another function, I cannot modify it. However, I changed `'Yokohama City-Tohoku'` to `'Yokohama-Tohoku'` in `x` to match your question description. I also changed `number` to a list and reordered the elements inside to match your desired output.

I always find that list comprehension is easier to understand, so I created `z` with it. You actually don't need to create `y_and_value`. Instead, you can use `zip(y, numbers)`.

You may want to research more on the differences between a set (unordered) and a list (ordered) in Python to understand better when to use which.

```
# x is a set (unordered) with tuples (immutable) inside
x = {('Hokkaido-Nikko', 'JAP'),
     ('Yokohama-Tohoku', 'JAP')
     }

# I changed y to a list (ordered)
y = ['Vaxjo-Lulea',
     'Hokkaido-Nikko',
     'Timra-Orebro',
     'Yokohama-Tohoku']

# I changed numbers to a list (ordered)
numbers = [1.12, 1.36, 1.44, 1.23]

# create list z with a if statement with a lambda function
z = [(city, [number]) for city, number in zip(y, numbers) if city in map(lambda q: q[0], x)]

print(z)
```

##### Output:

```
[('Hokkaido-Nikko', [1.36]), ('Yokohama-Tohoku', [1.23])]
```

Comment: You got close to what I'm looking for, however there is a problem in your code. In the (if) condition, I don't want to specify 'JAP', because I will have many different countries (eg JAP, ENG, FRA, ESP, KOR and other). Is there a way to edit your code and remove 'JAP'? Thank you

Comment: @Takao貴男 Updated with a lambda function. It will now access only the first elements of the tuples in `x`. The output remains the same, but the country code 'JAP' is no longer required.

Comment: With your answer I solved the shortened and simplified problem of this question,but didn't solve the real problem which involved putting these results into a datagrid.I will post another question,hope you will help me.Thanks for your code,it was helpful and you found solution to the question.Your answer,but also the other user's answer,are both right.I'm in trouble because I don't know which of the two to accept the question.I accept your answer because you have a lower account score and need to grow, and then your answer code is shorter than the other kind user's code.Voted and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is highly unclear, but I'm guessing something like:

```
x = [('Hokkaido-Nikko', 'JAP'),
     ('Yokohama-Tohoku', 'JAP'),
    ]
y = ['Vaxjo-Lulea',
     'Hokkaido-Nikko',
     'Timra-Orebro',
     'Yokohama-Tohoku',
     ]
numbers = [1.23, 1.44, 1.36, 1.12]

keep = {t[0] for t in x}


result = []
for key, value in zip(y, numbers):
    if key in keep:
        result.append((key, [value]))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('Hokkaido-Nikko', [1.44]),
 ('Yokohama-Tohoku', [1.12])]
```

Comment: You've come close to what I'm looking for, but that's not quite what I need. Now I'm going to sleep after a whole night on the PC because I'm tired. Tomorrow I will calmly review your code and comment on it. Thank you

Comment: I'm in trouble because I don't know which of the two to accept the question.You answered first, but I see that the other user has a lower account score and needs to grow, and then his answer code is shorter. I accepted his answer, but I wanted to upvote yours too.Please excuse me. Meanwhile, I upvoted your answer. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. With your answers, I solved the short problem of this question, but I didn't solve the real problem of inserting these results into a datagrid. I will post another question, hope you will help me. Thanks again, really thanks. I appreciated